# Stack image elements on top of each other without position absolute?

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I have a scenario where I want to stack images on top of each other for a slideshow. However, the context is a bit complex, so simply using `position: absolute` to stack them messes everything up. Not sure if I have any options here.

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/kesositexiwu/1)

```
<div class="article photo post">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="title vertical">Title</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content slideshow">
            <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3618143/2-large.jpg" style="max-width: 40vw; display: inline;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="article photo post">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="title vertical">Title</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content slideshow">
            <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3618143/1-large.jpg" style="max-width: 40vw; display: inline;">
            <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3618143/2-large.jpg" style="max-width: 40vw; display: inline;">
            <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3618143/3-large.jpg" style="max-width: 40vw; display: inline;">
            <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3618143/4-large.jpg" style="max-width: 40vw; display: inline;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.article {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 10px;
}

.article .inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
    -moz-box-direction: reverse;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
    -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.article .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
    margin: 0 0 -25px;
}

.article .title {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-out 0s;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-out 0s;
    transition: color .2s ease-out 0s;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

.article:hover .overlay {
   pointer-events: auto;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-out .75s; 
   -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease-out .75s;
   -o-transition: background-color .3s ease-out .75s;  
   transition: background-color .3s ease-out .75s;
}

.article:hover .title {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);

  -webkit-transition: color .5s ease-out .75s; 
  -moz-transition: color .5s ease-out .75s;
  -o-transition: color .5s ease-out .75s;  
  transition: color .5s ease-out .75s;
}

.vertical {
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
}

.content img {
    max-height: 70vh;
}
```

Comment: it's unclear what do you want to achieve. I mean, whatever it is, it's really easy, but your coding is contradictory with what I understand you want to achieve, so not sure if I understand correctly. Also, you don't have any slideshow. Then again, whatever it is, is very easy, I already tried several different scenarios and they all work

Comment: @Fabio There should be no fixed widths or heights. If you look at the first image you only have a vw width on the element (which is set randomly in my real scenario). There's no script for the slideshow yet as I first must solve how to stack the images first (simply adding pos: abs to the img elements in .content won't work).

Comment: What happens is that the img element in .content is assigned a random vw value, and that sets the width and height of the entire .article, letting overlay stretch out on top of it all.

Comment: sorry INT, what I mean is in terms of look: you want a slideshow with 5 images stacked one above the other, creating a really tall slideshow?

Comment: @Fabio Ah, no. They should all be on top of each other. 1-large.jpg, 2-large.jpg, 3-large.jpg, 4-large.jpg. I'll then use a script to change z-index of them to cycle through them. Like a gif effect.

Comment: Applying a specified width and height (such as 400px x 250px or whatever) of .article will allow me to put pos: abs on .content img, but I don't wanna set static values.

Comment: aaah got it. Then no, to clean the flow you need position:absolute (of course, you could use JS or JQuery and work your way around it) but with CSS this is the way to do it. This being said, what problems do you see in this scenario? It looks pretty simple and trivial, try getting rid of those ugly inline styles and add styles to the classes and elements via stylesheet and you'll see it's not very complicated. However, if you find a roadblock I'm not noticing, let us know and me or someone else will probably help you. As I said, it doesn't look as a complicated thing

Comment: @Fabio Have a look here: http://jsbin.com/rajutivitoqa/1. The second .article collapses onto the first .article and .overlay is not visible on hover anymore as it is on http://jsbin.com/kesositexiwu/1

Answer (score 0):

I think if you give to the div with class of `.content` a width of let's say 200px(or the width of the images), would work because the images won't have enaught space to go to right so they will go underneath the one above.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aus9br06/).

Comment: The problem with that is that each image (or set of images) in an article are scaled by a script with a randomized vw value. The mark up is done as it is to have the overlay scale to the size of the image etc.